# Laravel how to test if a checkbox is checked in a controller

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to get if checkbox is checked with:

In my view:

```php
<form data-toggle="validator" data-disable="false" role="form" action="/admin/role/add" method="post">
   <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
      <input name="test" id="test" type="checkbox" value="test">
      <label for="test" style="padding-left: 15px!important;">test</label>
   </div>
</form>
<form data-toggle="validator" data-disable="false" role="form" action="/admin/role/add" method="post">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="form-group pull-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

In my controller :

```php
public function createRole(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('test')) {
         new \App\Debug\Firephp('test', ['test' => true]);
    }
}
```

In my `web.php`:

```php
Route::post('/admin/role/add', 'AdminController@createRole')
```

but doesn't work for some reason.

How i can do?

Thanks for reply.

**EDIT 1 :**

It was my form that was poorly build.

Comment: I assume that your form isn't being POSTed? And you have referenced the facade in your controller? I find type-hinting Request works better for me in these situations.

Comment: yes i use POST method @Kurucu

Comment: This should work then, try also `if( Input::has('test')) `. And of course, if you're on Laravel 5, then using Request::input('test'); or type-hinting is the way forward: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests

Comment: $request->has('test') doesn't work for me @Kurucu

Comment: Check my answer below, to see how - you need a special function definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your real problem is that you have two separate forms. Your checkbox is in one form, your submit button is in a second form. I believe they both need to be in the same form. Otherwise your checkbox state is never returned, regardless of it's state.

In your view, try replacing the form markup you provided with this:

```
<form data-toggle="validator" data-disable="false" role="form" action="/admin/role/add" method="post">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
        <input name="test" id="test" type="checkbox" value="test">
        <label for="test" style="padding-left: 15px!important;">test</label>
    </div>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks a lot but we can't have two form with the same action ?

Comment: Form is like a box, where you put in the value (or values) you want to carry. If you put "checkbox" in one box, but carry(submit) the other, there is no checkbox in there.

Answer (score 11):

You can test it with:

```
if( Input::get('test', false) ) {
    // there is something for 'test'
} else {
    // there was no 'test' or it was false
}
```

Or

```
if( Request::input('test') ) { //...
```

Or

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if( $request->has('test') ){
        //...
    }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests

Comment: i already did it :                                                                                               public function createRole(Request $request)
    {
        if( $request->has('test')) {
            new \App\Debug\Firephp('name_role', ['name_role' =>'true']);
        }

        new \App\Debug\Firephp('name_role', ['name_role' => $request->input('name_role')]);
    }

Comment: but  if( $request->has('test') return false @Kurucu

Comment: can you post your html form; and your controller code (snippets of each, if necessary)?

Answer (score 6):

Checkbox sends info **only** when it's checked, so what you do is, you check, if the value is present. It's easier, if you use method with `Request $request` than using direct inputs:

```
if (isset($request->test)) {
    // checked
}
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests

Comment: one more thing  i came across. if there is a `value=''` left by mistake  inside `input` tag seems it wont  turn input as "set" even if got manually checked !? removed that and now works ok  .

Answer (score 0):

I made an class and put this method into it:

```
//This function is used to insert missing index key when checkboxes are used
public static function checkboxHelper($request_array, $key)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($key,$request_array)){
        $request_array[$key]=0;
    }
    else{
        $request_array[$key]=1;
    }

    return $request_array;
}
```

This method is taking array from $request object and inserting missing key (name of checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a value in the checkbox like the following.

```
if ($request->checkbox_name) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that

```
$request->test ? $request->test : 'false';
```