# How should I declare controller using checkbox?

Tags: php, html, laravel

How should I declare controller using checkbox in this situation?

Controller:

```
return User::create([
    'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
    'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
    'usertype' => $data['usertype'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);
```

Code:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('usertype') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" >
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="usertype" value="mokytojas" class="custom-control-input" required autofocus>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline1">Mokytojas</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="usertype" value ="paskaitu_lektorius" class="custom-control-input" >
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline2">Paskaitų lektorius</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "_declare controller using checkbox_" What does that mean? Which checkbox?

Comment: i am using checkbox in laravel, I want to send its value to the database

Comment: And you don't know how/where to do it? Add it to the array in your `User::create()` method like the other fields. What have you tried, what doesn't work? Do you get errors?

Comment: The form will send true or false on the request, so you should expect a boolean on your back-end

Comment: @kerbholz Well, you see there are two checkboxes and I want that the database would get the value of the one selected checkbox. I just do not know how to code this in the controller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5, how to test if a Checkbox is checked in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411283/laravel-5-how-to-test-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-a-controller)

Comment: fyi, those are `radio` inputs, not a checkbox. It's handled the same way your other input elements are handled. Assuming you have set up validation for that input and `$data` contains the validated request `$data['usertype']` should either contain "mokytojas" or "paskaitu_lektorius".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966620/laravel-get-values-of-checkboxes) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411283/laravel-5-how-to-test-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-a-controller) would give you some basic information about how to do it. I suggest you to perform research before posting a question here.